# How does laravel work with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Is it possible to load multiple views of laravel on a  element of html of a single layout view dynamically? Is there any ajax package or equivalent package to enable laravel load views without the need to reload the entire page?

Comment: might want to try vue

Comment: Is that a package? Give me the url please.

Comment: @MinilikTesfaye Vue (https://vuejs.org/v2) is a modern Javascript framework. It's somewhat already built into Laravel's front-end system (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Jquery to do ajax requests but this is really old fashion way Laravel already ships with Vue.js and you can switch it to React.js simply which they are a trend technologies in the front-end world.

for me I prefer vue.js it is easier to learn simple to use and super fast also it's only 20Kb in size so the response time would be really fast.

You can find vue [docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)

but if you are completely new to vue and such technologies I strongly suggest that you watch [this course](https://www.udemy.com/vuejs-2-the-complete-guide/) on Udemy I learned vue from it really smooth explanation in a simple manner this guy is a professional.

Hope you found this helpful , good luck.